# How to get all the string before an empty space in postgres?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

So basically I need to get a part of the postcode string, all before an empty space

my current query is

```
select postcode, left(postcode, length(postcode) - strpos(' ', postcode)) 
from postcodetable
```

But it just doesn't return the post code correctly, example:
1st column is `NW1 1AA`, 2nd column should just be `NW1` but instead it just repeats the first column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your arguments to `strpos()` are in the wrong order.  So you can do:

```
select postcode, left(postcode, length(postcode) - strpos(postcode, ' '))
from (values ('NW1 1AA')) v(postcode);
```

You can also do this using `substring()` with regular expressions:

```
select postcode, substring(postcode from '[^ ]+'::text)
```

Comment: Oh it kinda worked now but there's still something wrong, my string of WC1B 4HH got trummed into WC1 instead of WC1B. Using your 2nd option it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Not only inverted arguments in `strpos` function, but also the 2nd parameter of `left` function is the number of characters to pick from the left.

Relating to official postgres docs:

> left(str text, n int)
>
> Return first n characters in the string. When n is negative, return all but last |n| characters.

So the correct query would be:

```
select postcode, left(postcode, strpos(postcode, ' ')) from postcodetable
```